# inverse rounded corners

Tags: boxes, tcolorbox

is there a way to use `tcolorbox` (or some other package) to create *inverse* rounded corners.

By using the following code

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!5!white,
    colframe=red!75!black,
    arc=4mm,
    sharp corners,
    rounded corners=east
  ]
  This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\end{tcolorbox}
```

i get:

[image]

However, I'd rather want[image]

I tried setting a negative arc radius, but this gives weirdo results (putting the inverse corners *outside* of the box)

Comment: use a rectangle then over-print a white box with red curved left border?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible with an `overlay`, but at the moment, I am struggling with the size keys, i.e. to figure out the height and border width of the box.

Warning, this won't work if there's a title or thick bottom or top rules.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\makeatletter

\newtcolorbox{myinversearcbox}[1][]{%
  enhanced jigsaw,
  colback=red!5!white,
    colframe=red!75!black,
    sharp corners,
    rightrule=0pt,
    overlay={enhanced,
      \path[draw=red!75!black,line width=\kvtcb@top@rule,fill=white] ([xshift=0cm,yshift=-\kvtcb@left@rule/2]frame.north east) arc (90:270:\tcb@height/2-\kvtcb@left@rule/2);
    },
    #1
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}



\begin{myinversearcbox}
  This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.

\end{myinversearcbox}




\end{document}
```

[image]